# Regex to match two words along with initials

Tags: regex

I have a string with two words, namely firstname and lastname. They can appear in any pattern such as:

```
Brad Pitt
Brad P
B Pitt
P Brad
Pitt B
Pitt Brad
```

It should contain only the above strings (only two words) and any other string should be disqualified. There can either be a space or comma separating the words in the string. Can someone help in providing a regex to match the above case? I tried with **/^(?=.*\bbrad|b|p|pitt\b)(?=.*\bbrad|p|b|pitt\b).*$/i** but that only validates the words and is not returning the correct matches.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: *"Match above case"*? Which one? What's a correct match? Do I look like a mindreader?

Comment: I was referring to the possibilities of occurrences of Brad Pitt. It can appear in the ways which I mentioned but not in any other way.

Comment: If you are not able to help or understand my problem, you could have asked and I could have provided you with more details. There is not a reason you should downvote this!!

Comment: You should write an understandable question from the beginning (read the FAQ on how to ask questions). If the question is not clear for me, I'm on my right to downvote it. You need to learn to live with it in SO.

Comment: Thats fine. you are the only one who seems to have not understood and embarked on criticizing. On the other hand, I received an answer and am going to accept it coz it solved my issue.

Comment: Good for you someone understood it. I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
/^(Brad P(itt)?)|(B(rad)? Pitt)|(P(itt)? Brad)|(Pitt B(rad)?)$/i
```

If you will accept `B P` or `P B`, you can siplify it to:

```
/^(B(rad)? P(itt)?)|(P(itt)? B(rad)?)$/i
```

Comment: I believe you can remove both instances of `(rad)?` from your first regex without changing the results.

Answer (score 0):

> It should contain only the above strings (**only two words**) and any
>   other string should be disqualified. **There can either be a space or
>   comma separating the words in the string**.

```
  ^([A-z][A-z]+)[ ]+([A-z][A-z]+)$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vladimir. Using this I am not able to validate the [ ] expression. I am trying to provide the following
/^((Brad)[ ]+(P(itt))?)|(B(rad)? Pitt)|(P(itt)? Brad)|(Pitt B(rad)?)$/i
but it does not work

Comment: ^((Brad[ ]+Pitt)|(Pitt[ ]+Brad))$